# How to add "\x" after every 2 words on a string in Javascript?

Tags: regex, string, hex

I want to add "\x" after every 2 characters on a string, and also in the beginning. For example, the string `596d396962334a76` would become `\x59\x6d\x39\x69\x62\x33\x4a\x76`. 
I tried this code: `"596d396962334a76".match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("/");` but it gives this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid hexadecimal escape sequence`.

Comment: That is bacause you tried `.join("\x")`, right? You need two backslashes, `.join("\\x")`

Comment: You state `add "\x" after every 2 characters`, but your example shows that you want to prefix `\x` to every 2 chars. Which is it?

Comment: **Wrong Dupe:** How is replacement of backward slash with forward slash same as adding `\x` every 2 words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.match` you can use `.replace`:

```js
var s = '596d396962334a76';

var r = s.replace(/../g, '\\x$&');

console.log(r);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JC1ptA/1)

Here we match any 2 characters using `/../g` regex and append `\x` before each match by using replacement expression: `\\x$&`.